# How to KEEP only first occurence data in Libre Office Calc (with two column filter)

Tags: database, if-statement, conditional-operator, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I have a large database of car makes and models color auto code structured in these columns:
Make - Model - Description - Code
and about 14000 rows.

I need to have the database with only the first occurrence of each Make - Model

example:
Alfa romeo - 145 - Blue - 205
Alfa romeo - 145 - Black - 201

I Should only have the first row of each individual make and model in my libre office Calc sheet

so in the above example I should have only
Alfa romeo - 145 - Blue - 205 and so on for every make and model...

How could I do?

I tried with the simple filter, inserting the two affected columns equal to non-empty and arriving the duplication, but nothing changes. Then I tried with the countifcondition, but I didn't quite understand how to use it in this case.